# Android - more than 2 simultaneous touches

Tags: android, multi-touch

Can android recognize more than two simultaneous touches (3, 4, etc...)? Is the number of supported touches device-specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the amount of multi-touch points is determined by the devices touchscreen hardware and whether multi-touch was implemented in it's ROM.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Answer (score 0):

Generally yes, but the hardware support including the number of touches depends on the device.  Always provide also an alternate method of accessing your application.

Please see [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html) for more details.